# Calculate % of filtered values from all values in Excel Pivot Table

Tags: excel, pivot-table, excel-2013

I have this pivot table that currently shows how many students failed in a particular subject in a particular academic year. That is, it is now filtered by Pass_Status Fail(which can be either Pass or Fail):

[image: Excel]

For example, in Business Computing subject there were 3 people in 2002-2003, and two of them failed. That is what the table shows right now.

But I want to convert it into percentage, considering the number of all the students who took the subject in an academic year as total.

In the case of Business Computing in 2002-2003, I want to show 66% (2 failed of 3).

How can I do that?

Comment: you would have to display both, fails and pass and show the percentage of total. I guess there is otherwise no way to determine the total participants of the course and therefore no way to compute the percentage.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, don't you just right-click on any value (use the 2 for the example), go to submenu "Show Values As",  and choose % of Row Total??

Comment: The thing is I dont want the % of row total :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by creating a new calculated field with this formula:

```
percent_of_fails:=CALCULATE(COUNT(ModuleRegistration[ID]), FILTER(ModuleRegistration, ModuleRegistration[Pass_Status] = "Fail")) / COUNT(ModuleRegistration[ID])
```